# PowerShell | Need some performance improvement

Tags: performance, powershell, 7zip

I have written a powershell script for archival of old log files or say some output file of web application which is in TBs but the script is taking very long time. I have done some improvement but not able to speed up more from here.

Code:

```
#region Archive Files using 7zip

[cmdletbinding()]
Param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage = "Path needs to be with trailing slash at the end of location." )]
[string]$SourceFilesPath
)

$7zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$FilePath = ""

foreach ( $filename in $(Get-ChildItem $SourceFilesPath -Force -Recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()}))
{
    $FilePath = Get-ItemProperty $filename.FullName
    $ZipFilePath = $filename.Directory.ToString() + "\ZippedFiles" + "\Archive_" + $filename.LastWriteTime.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".7z"

    $tempPath = ("-w"+"C:\Temp")
    $OutputData = &$7zip a $tempPath -t7z $ZipFilePath $FilePath
    $OutputData
    if ($OutputData -contains "Everything is OK")
    {
        Remove-Item $FilePath -Force
        Write-Output "File removed $FilePath"
    }
    Get-Item $ZipFilePath | ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime = $filename.LastWriteTime}
}

#endregion
```

Comment: 7zip is using only 2 cores in the default LZMA mode. Switch to using LZMA2 compression to engage all CPU cores, or specify a faster compression mode via the command line switches.

Comment: I can do that but don't think it will give much of improvement as the file sizes are not big. FIles are mostly in kb and max is 5 mb but the number of files are huge. so may be I need something in filters or any other way of filtering which can be faster.

Comment: Big number of files * small size = big overall size = long compression time.

Comment: Ok Thanks, the compression is little faster now by adding -m0=lzma2 in command not much improvement.

Comment: Well, any performance improvement must start with measuring the current bottleneck, which means tools like process explorer or the built-in resource monitor - maybe your disk speed is the bottleneck. Especially if it's not SSD. And even more so if it's a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
#region Archive Files using 7zip

[cmdletbinding()]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = 'Path needs to be with trailing slash at the end of location.' )]
    [string]$SourceFilesPath
)
Import-Module ..\Invoke-Parallel.ps1 # Download from PSGallery

$7zip = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'

$fileToArchive = $(Get-ChildItem $SourceFilesPath -Force -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
})
$counter = 0
$groupSize = 2000 # Will group items by 2,000 increments
$groups = $fileToArchive | Group-Object -Property {
    [math]::Floor($counter++ / $groupSize) 
}
$groups

# This will spawn multiple instances of 7zip - depending on how many groups of 2,000 files exist
$groups.Group | Invoke-Parallel -ScriptBlock {
    $FilePath = $null
    $fileName = $_
    $FilePath = Get-ItemProperty -Path $fileName.FullName
    $ZipFilePath = $fileName.Directory.ToString() + '\ZippedFiles' + '\Archive_' + $fileName.LastWriteTime.ToString('MMddyyyy') + '.7z'

    $tempPath = ('-w'+'C:\Temp')
    $OutputData = &$Using:7zip a $tempPath -t7z $ZipFilePath $FilePath
    $OutputData
    if ($OutputData -contains 'Everything is OK')
    {
        Remove-Item $FilePath -Force
        Write-Output -InputObject "File removed $FilePath"
    }
    Get-Item $ZipFilePath | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $_.LastWriteTime = $fileName.LastWriteTime
    }
}
```

Comment: After some correction in script. Its working on my local machine but not on server. When I looked through debugging I found there is a check condition for PSVersion in Invoke-parallel script and I have PSVersion on 2.0 on my server 2008 R2. Btw, the error is ""

Comment: Get-RunspaceData : The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an invalid object. It must result in a comma
nd name, script block or CommandInfo object.
At E:\DevOps\Scripts\Invoke-Parallel.ps1:569 char:37
+                     Get-RunspaceData <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression,Get-RunspaceData

Comment: Invoke-Parallel requires v3+.